# Enable Azure MFA by changing user state

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Trying to activate MFA per user as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates#enable-azure-mfa-by-changing-user-state however

1. via UI => Selecting the user does not show the quick steps to Enable.
2. via PowerShell => Successfully installed `Install-Module MSOnline` but then `Connect-MsolService` runs into *Connect-MsolService : The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.*
3. List item

How can MFA be enabled per user in AAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quick steps to enable mfa for **guest users** via this UI.

[image]

If you choose your tenant users, the button will show up.

[image]

If you want to enforce multi-factor authentication for B2B guest users, you can follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-tutorial-require-mfa).